# Silverlight TLS/SSL

Tags: c#, silverlight, ssl

Does anybody know any solution/walkaround to provide TLS/SSL support for TCP sockets in Silverlight x.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your Silverlight 4 application as trusted, you can use [SSL/TLS components for Silverlight](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php), which are included in SecureBlackbox .NET.

If you have Silverlight 3 application or untrusted Silverlight 4 application, you can also use these components, yet you would be restricted by socket classes to only certain port numbers and only if the destination system has a policy available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have you tried it with your SL applications?

Comment: Well, actually we developed these components and yes, we tested them :).

Answer (score 0):

No need for Third-Party API/SDK.  You can simply use the SslStream Class (Microsoft), which is standard in all-versions of .NET.  There still may be security restrictions on Siverlight application, but no need for separate deployment, licensing or references (dependancy)